# cargar una URL con un array en java

Tags: java, array, url

estoy copiando una url con este metodo, pero como tengo muchas web quisiera saber si un array puede servir. intente hacerlo pero da error, como tendria que hacerlo?

```
                  URL url = new URL("http//xxx.com");
                  URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

              // mi intento de hacerlo funcionar con un array

                  URL url = new URL(array[1])  
                   URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
```

que es lo que podria que hacer? 
gracias por leer, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para trabajar con un arreglo que tiene varias URL primero hay que declarar el arreglo e inicializarlo indicándole la cantidad de URL que necesitas.

```
int cant = 10;
URL[] urls = new URL[cant];
.
.
.
URL url = urls[1];  
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
```

Una desventaja de utilizar arreglos, es que el número de URL que puedes almacenar está limitado a la longitud del arreglo. Dicho esto la mejor solución sería utilizando una lista (Aunque si tu número de URL no cambia, basta con el arreglo).

```
ArrayList<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();
.
.
.
URL url = urls.get(1);  
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
```

Comment: la cantidad de url es fija, asi que no tendria problemas de usarlo de la primer forma. 
 pero como cargo las direcciones web en el array? porque del modo basico no me funciona.

int cant = 10;
URL[] urls = new URL[cant];
urls[0]= https://xxx.com;  ??
urls[1]= "https://";  ??

Comment: Recuerda que el arreglo es de URL no de String, por lo que lo único que carga son URL. Para hacerlo en la primera posición sería **urls[0] = new URL("http//aaa.com");**

Comment: Todo perfecto, muchas gracias Lazaro!